# How to get only one record from left table against each record from right table

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have two tables, one for some kind of devices and the other for their locations (using this table to keep a track record of location history). Tables' schemas are:

1. tbl_Devices:

   - DeviceSrNumber (bigint, not null, pk)
   - Some other columns
2. tbl_DeviceLocation

   - SrNumber (bigint, not null, pk, identity)
   - DeviceSrNumber (bigint, not null)
   - Location (varchar(300), not null)
   - AddDateTime (DateTime, not null)

What I need is `DeviceSrNumber`, last `Location`, last Location set `AddDateTime`

What I am doing now:

```
SELECT
    DeviceSrNumber,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) Location
        FROM tbl_DeviceLocation
        WHERE (DeviceSrNumber = d.DeviceSrNumber)
        ORDER BY AddDateTime DESC
    ) AS 'Location',
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) AddDateTime
        FROM tbl_DeviceLocation
        WHERE (DeviceSrNumber = d.DeviceSrNumber)
        ORDER BY AddDateTime DESC
    ) AS 'AddDateTime '
FROM
    tbl_Devices AS d
```

But I need to do it with a join in a cleaner way, because according to my knowledge, a sub-query is not efficient and not recommended in a large-scale database.

*Note: It is a small part of a large project, where it will deal with millions of records.*

Comment: Do you have any `Indexes` on `tbl_DeviceLoation`?

Comment: Yes. I have clustered index on SrNumber (bigint, not null, identity, PK)
And also there is a check on "Location" column. But does it have anything to do with our problem.

Comment: The `CHECK` is a _constraint_ not an _INDEX_, so you have just one index.

Comment: Subquery perfomance depends on the query & the optimizer. As in every optimization issue, it & other options should be measured in practice. Of course there are tendencies documented & observed/hypothesized for a particular implementation--here we can suspect that certain duplicate code might not be well optimized & seek a single mention of tbl_DeviceLocation, presumably via a join. What did you try like that? PS Clarify via post edits, not comments. Also for code questions give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT        
      d.DeviceSrNumber
    , dl.Location    LastLocation
    , dl.AddDateTime LastLocationSetDateTime
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.DeviceSrNumber ORDER BY AddDateTime DESC) RN 
    FROM 
        tbl_Devices d
    JOIN tbl_DeviceLocation dl ON dl.DeviceSrNumber = d.DeviceSrNumber 
) D 
WHERE 
    RN = 1
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT        
  d.DeviceSrNumber
, MAX(dl.Location)  LastLocation
, MAX(dl.AddDateTime) LastLocationSetDateTime
FROM 
    tbl_Devices d
JOIN tbl_DeviceLocation dl ON dl.DeviceSrNumber = d.DeviceSrNumber 
GROUP BY d.DeviceSrNumber
ORDER BY AddDateTime DESC
```

Comment: Dear  @iSR5, I don't want locations added in last 24 hours, I need location of each device, and its time, without having any concern either they were update in last 24 hours or not.

Comment: @RaiArslan then remove the WHERE clause, this will grab all devices along with their locations and its time.

Comment: Just to make it clear again, I wanted last location, not all locations assigned to a device.

Comment: @RaiArslan recheck the query, I've updated. Is that what you need ?

Comment: Dear @iSR5, i don't wanted to use a sub-query. it is producing same result as my initial query. Kindly let me know if there is any way to do it using joins. If yes please tell me.

Comment: Dear it is not helping. kindly have a look on result of existing working query.   

| DeviceSrNumber | Location | AddDateTime  |    
| 100230952234 | Franchise | 2019-01-04 15:27:47.050  
 |  
| 100232000000 | Franchise | 2019-01-04 15:27:47.057 |  
| 100232000001 | Franchise | 2019-01-04 15:27:47.063 |  
| 100232000002 | Franchise | 2019-01-04 15:27:47.070 |  
| 100232000003 | Franchise | 2019-01-04 16:09:57.917 |  
| 100232000004 | Region | 2019-01-04 17:14:59.637 |  
| 100232000005 | Franchise | 2019-01-04 16:09:57.923 |  
| 100232000006 | Franchise | 2019-01-04 16:40:15.590|

Comment: @RaiArslan to help you better, please update your post with a sample and your expected results from that sample.

Comment: The first query looks good to me. It is a very common way to deal with this kind of problems in SQL Server and usually quite efficient, with proper indexing. In this case, an index on `(DeviceSrNumber, AddDateTime)` will likely help a lot.

Comment: An index on `(DeviceSrNumber, AddDateTime) INCLUDE (Location)` will be an even better one, if you can afford it.

Comment: @iSR5 and you don't need to the join to `tbl_Devices`.

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ well, it might be needed and actually used in the final query, but the OP might just simplify it for us to avoid complicity. So, we stick with what we have, if we have a full knowledge on the logic and requirements of that query, then we can decide which is needed and which is not.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because the first query is good. The 2nd query (after "update") is plainly incorrect and should be removed.

Comment: Dear @iSR5 thanks for your support. Your first query was so much helping. But I had short time when I asked this question. I was not getting a solution and it was a becoming a bottleneck for the whole project delivery. Then eventually I decided to go with sub-query, a working but nasty solution (IMHO). Now I decided to compare your query with mine, and find it life savior. I am going to replace it in next CR. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will be much more efficient on this way:

```
SELECT D.DeviceSrNumber, 
       L.Location, 
       L.AddDateTime 
FROM        tbl_Devices D
OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT TOP (1) DL.Location, DL.AddDateTime
    FROM tbl_DeviceLocation DL
    WHERE D.DeviceSrNumber = DL.DeviceSrNumber
    ORDER BY DL.AddDateTime DESC
   ) L;
```

Comment: You miss something in the last.

Comment: I think you refer to a closing parenthesis. Yes, I have already added, thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Don't you miss anything else? eg: `L.Location` ?? L??

Comment: Right, this is the semantically equivalent. Sorry, maybe I assumed that there were always some Location for each device

Comment: Still need an alias @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting the issues mentioned in comments but please take a look for yourself. The method itself makes sense, it just had a number of issues and I believe all the points have been addressed now. Feel free to edit further as necessary

Comment: Many thanks !!! Yes, I was in several items at the same time and not enough focused on replying correctly. Happy that several people realized and improved the response !!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it will select one single data using the latest AddDateTime

```
SELECT top(1) D.DeviceSrNumber, L.Location,L.AddDateTime 
FROM tbl_Devices AS D 
JOIN tbl_DeviceLoation AS L ON D.DeviceSrNumber  = L.DeviceSrNumber 
WHERE D.DeviceSrNumber  = L.DeviceSrNumber  order by L.AddDateTime desc
```

**Update**

I tried this and it select distinct record according to the latest record. hope this solve it

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT D.DeviceSrNumber, L.Location,L.AddDateTime , RN= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  D.DeviceSrNumber ORDER BY  D.DeviceSrNumber)
FROM  tbl_Devices AS D LEFT JOIN tbl_DeviceLoation AS L ON D.DeviceSrNumber  = L.DeviceSrNumber
WHERE D.DeviceSrNumber  = L.DeviceSrNumber group by  D.DeviceSrNumber, L.Location,L.AddDateTime )
SELECT * FROM CTE where RN=1 order by CTE.AddDateTime desc
```

Comment: Dear @muhdamean , It would not work, because we need to list all devices along with their locations.

Comment: i tried using another method and it works for me kindly try it out. @RaiArslan